# Tags insertion jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jquery plugin that will handle Tags insertion (the same as SO uses here when you put in your tags) - that is, trimming, cutting, and class insertion.

Anyone knows anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQueryTag-it!](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)
*Simple and configurable tag editing widget with autocomplete support.*